# In WP, can't include_once() same file in both header.php and footer.php

Tags: php, wordpress

There are 3 .php files:

vars.php

```
    $foo = 'bar';
```

header.php:

```
    include_once("vars.php");
    echo "In header: $foo";
```

footer.php:

```
    include_once("vars.php");
    echo "In footer: $foo";
```

In the above situation, $foo is not set in footer.php. If I remove the `include_once()` in header.php, then $foo is set in footer.php, but not header.php.

I'm guessing I'm making a silly somewhere, but for the life of me I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `..._once()` functions don't care WHERE the include/require occured. Once a file has been included, it'll never been include_once/require_once again anywhere during that particular script execution run.

If you need to include it multiple times in different locations, then don't use the _once() variants.

Comment: But in that case, shouldn't the already included file's variables be available down the line? I was under the impression that the `..._once()` functions only served to prevent duplication.

Comment: Files are loaded into the scope of the include directive. If you header is included inside a function call, then your included variables would exist only within that function, but you'd still use up the global "load once" slot.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not included a second time is because you told it to `include_once` - *once*.

At any rate, `$foo` should be included if you keep the `include_once` in header.php. Make sure you're not changing `$foo` down the road before footer.php.